# Python http2lib authentication request login returning 401

Tags: python, flask, httplib2

I have a simple Flask app which I am using to get familiar with the `flask_httpauth` library. I can login via my browser, issuing a `GET` request and then inputting the user and the password. I was trying to do the same with http2lib using `request` but it is always returning 401 Unauthorized Access.  Below is my code for the flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_httpauth import HTTPDigestAuth


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "asasdasd"
auth = HTTPDigestAuth()

users = {
    "Tim":"1234",
    "Susan": "bye"
    }


@app.route('/greeting')
def greeting():
    return "<h1>Welcome to Flask-HTTPAuth’s</h1>"

@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def index():
    return "Hello"

@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users.get(username)
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

As well for the request, which is returning 401:

```
import httplib2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = httplib2.Http()
    h.add_credentials('Tim','1234')
    resp = h.request('http://localhost:5000/','GET')
    print(resp)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's because on your server you're using Digest auth and your client Basic.

Try changing it to:

```
 from flask_httpauth import HTTPDigestAuth

 url = 'http://localhost:5000/'
 requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('Time', '1234'))
```

Comment: Nope, I get a type error now.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "authenticated_app_tester.py", line 9, in <module>
    requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('Time', '1234'))
  ...
TypeError: 'HTTPDigestAuth' object is not callable

Comment: Got it it is actually from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth. Thank you Dan!

Comment: Is there a way in order to make it work with httplib2 instead of requests.auth?